# Error on sonarQube scan in jenkins on Windows machine

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, devops, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I am trying to run the soanrQube scan from my jenkins node, Sonar scanner version is SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141 SonarQube server is SonarQube server 5.6.4. getting the following error, Can any one help me on this.

```
05:13:57.811 DEBUG: Execution execute
    05:13:58.100 DEBUG: Publish global mode
    05:13:58.193 INFO: Load global repositories
    05:13:58.243 DEBUG: GET 401 http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX/batch/global | time=50ms
    05:13:58.244 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    05:13:58.245 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
    05:13:58.245 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    05:13:58.245 INFO: Total time: 1.179s
    05:13:58.279 INFO: Final Memory: 9M/491M
    05:13:58.279 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    05:13:58.279 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    05:13:58.280 ERROR: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller
    05:13:58.280 ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache
    05:13:58.280 ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalSettings
    05:13:58.280 ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.protocol.input.GlobalRepositories
    05:13:58.280 ERROR: Caused by: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
    05:13:58.280 ERROR: 
    05:13:58.280 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx8192m
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! ahp@0.0.0 sonar: `sonar-scanner`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the ahp@0.0.0 sonar script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\apps\node-v10.16.2-win-x64\_logs\2019-11-15T10_13_58_358Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved by giving correct API token. That was authentication issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other log file? What you have posted, doesn't give any hint as to what is going wrong. Have you looked in $SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/web.log? That should point you in the right direction.